# Cross-browser JS standardizer

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, w3c

Is there a library which makes all browser's JS interfaces comply to W3C standards?

For example, one that will add `addEventListener` to IE8, based on `attachEvent`.

EDIT 2022. `core-js` was created a year after this question. I guess it wasn't that much off-topic, huh?

Comment: Yes. Try this: http://badassjs.com/post/20294238453/webkit-js-yes-it-has-finally-happened-browser :)

Comment: @KonstantinK a bit late/early for april fools;)

Comment: @KonstantinK, one could use Bellard's in-browser Linux, run graphical interface in it, and then open some browser in it, if it wasn't late 2013, when browsers are so incredibly slow. So it doesn't seem like an april's fool joke to me :)

Comment: http://dean.edwards.name/IE7/

Comment: @dandavis Awesome! You've just proven it's a techinically possible task.

Comment: of course it's possible, that's why they opened up Object.defineProperty to modify DOM prototypes in IE8: so you could make IE8+ behave like W3 browsers (adding stuff like classList, dataset, firstElementChild, etc) . Most conflicts on a patched system stem from the scripts using browser sniffing instead of object detection. if you patch IE, you don't need the IE branch of many common low-level libraries. you can also include JS-only upgrades (also missing) like http://danml.com/js/f.js (es5) and http://danml.com/js/es6.js to bring the core JS up-to-date (as much as possible).

Comment: Actually, such libraries are called `polyfill` (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill). Greetz go to Pavlo, Quentin, bfavaretto, Mario and iCodez for their great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every modern javascript framework offers you methods to even out these inconsistencies in the browsers js implementation (like jQuery's `on` handles addEventListener/attachEvent). Most of these frameworks however don't use the approach to alter the host objects (which is considered problematic) but their methods internally map to the according functions available in the specific browser.

I suggest you try one of those many popular frameworks (like e.g. jQuery, MooTools or Dojo to name only a few of the more popular ones).

I suggest to NOT use a framework which alters the host objects directly (as some of them tried in the earlier days and later discovered that this causes many problems).

Comment: The problem is that jQuery and other JS frameworks are not standardized by W3C and add a bit of overhead to every action. Also, they're in no way complete due to the variety of JS interfaces (i.e. XSL). Nevertheless, we have to use them.

Comment: Is there a good explanation on problems with native object modification?

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph And a library which enhances "all browsers" to the same level would not have overhead? What you ask is impossible. The only thing like this would be some kind of plugin like [Google Chrome Frame](http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?hl=en&prefersystemlevel=true).

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph http://perfectionkills.com/extending-built-in-native-objects-evil-or-not/ would be one example talking about extending host objects.

Comment: There will be an overhead anyway, and I can't tell if it would be smaller when modifing native objects, because I haven't seen such a solution. Why do you say it's impossible to accomplish the said task? BTW That article says the main problem with native/host object modification is a chance to lose compliance to W3C specs, which obviously wouldn't happen with the library I'm asking about.